# regex match not outputting the adjacent matches javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

i was experimenting on regex in javascript. Then i came across an issue such that let consider string `str = "+d+a+"`, I was trying to output those characters in the string which are surrounded by `+`, I used `str.match(/\+[a-z]\+/ig)`, so here what I'm expecting is `["+d+","+a+"]`, but what i got is just `["+d+"]`, `"+a+"` is not showing in the output. Why?

Comment: `*` is a regex metacharacter and needs to be escaped if you mean to use it literally.

Answer (score 1):

`.match(/.../g)` returns all *non-overlapping* matches. Your regex requires a `+` sign on each side. Given your target string:

```
+d+a+
^^^
  ^^^
```

Your matches would have to overlap in the middle in order to return `"+a+"`.

You can use look-ahead and a manual loop to find overlapping matches:

```js
var str = "+d+a+";

var re = /(?=(\+[a-z]\+))/g;

var matches = [], m;
while (m = re.exec(str)) {
    matches.push(m[1]);
    re.lastIndex++;
}

console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

With regex, when a character gets consumed with a match, then it won't count for the next match.

For example, a regex like `/aba/g` wouldn't find 2 aba's in a string like "ababa".
Because the second "a" was already consumed.
However, that can be overcome by using a positive lookahead `(?=...)`.
Because lookaheads just check what's behind without actually consuming it.
So a regex like `/(ab)(?=(a))/g` would return 2 capture groups with 'ab' and 'a' for each 'aba'.

But in this case it just needs to be followed by 1 fixed character '+'.
So it can be simplified, because you don't really need capture groups for this one.

**Example snippet:**

```js
var str = "+a+b+c+";

var matches = str.match(/\+[a-z]+(?=\+)/g).map(function(m){return m + '+'});

console.log(matches);
```